# Best reference / crib sheet for AWK

Tags: reference, awk, gawk

In a series of similar questions, what is the best AWK reference you've ever seen?

If there isn't really one (I've yet to find the grail), perhaps we could compile one in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

[The AWK Programming Language](http://www.amazon.co.uk/AWK-Programming-Language-Alfred-Aho/dp/020107981X), by Aho, Kernighan and Weinberger is the best. The initials of the author's names should tell you why...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *Effective AWK Programming* by *Arnold Robbins*. You can get free pdf copy [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I needed to know something about AWK I always went to my copy of [UNIX in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/unixnut3/chapter/ch11.html).  Now I see that there is a SED/AWK in a Nutshell [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922255) and [pocket guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003528).  The former was enough for what I needed.  Haven't used the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

[This reference card PDF](http://www.cs.mtsu.edu/~neal/awkcard.pdf) is pretty comprehensive for a crib sheet, yet it's concise enough to allow you to find what you need quickly. It also includes information on the mawk and gawk implementations.

Comment: The link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

I find this site to be useful (it hasn't let me down yet):

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

I also find this Cookbook style site quite inspirational:

http://student.northpark.edu/pemente/awk/awk1line.txt

Hope these help.